# how to skip the first optional param but insert the next one

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am using the following code got it from https://docs.min.io/docs/javascript-client-api-reference.html

```
var Fs = require('fs')
var file = '/tmp/40mbfile'
var fileStream = Fs.createReadStream(file)
var fileStat = Fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }
  minioClient.putObject('mybucket', '40mbfile', fileStream, stats.size, function(err, objInfo) {
      if(err) {
          return console.log(err) // err should be null
      }
   console.log("Success", objInfo)
  })
})
```

and it works fine. However I need to send the metadata as well but not size and both are optional

[image]

How can I send the optional metadata but no size in a way that the library can still works properly?

I want something like this

```
 minioClient.putObject('mybucket', '40mbfile', fileStream, metadata, function(err, objInfo) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this library specifically, but the standard way of skipping optional values is just passing the value as null:

```js
minioClient.putObject('mybucket', '40mbfile', fileStream, null, meta, function(err, objInfo) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err) // err should be null
  }
  console.log("Success", objInfo)
})
```